# Custom made a* Path finding isn't working very well

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I am making a pathfinding algorithm on a map with coordinates, for a project with rivers. I looked at how a* worked, and I started to understand it, so I made it in my own code. The issue is that is doesn't work at all. The pathfinder is only making the first two squares of the river, and then just giving up. I do not know the issue.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
public  class APath 
{
    public bool[,] open;
    private bool[,] closed;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    public int currentX, currentY;

    public void FindPath(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {

        open = new bool[75,75];// stores path
        open[startX, startY] = true;
        bool[,] opens = open;
        closed = new bool[75,75] ;
        currentY = startY;
        currentX = startX;
        bool end = false;

        for(int l = 0; l< 1000; l++) //while loop went on forever. Had to use for loop
        {

            float[][] adjacent = Adjacent(currentX,currentY,endX,endY,startX,startY);//gets adjacent squares
            float min = adjacent[0][2];//creates temp min

            int per = 0;// storage of refrence for later

            for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)// checks adjacent squares
            {




                if (adjacent[i][2] < min)//if there is a new min
                {


                    min = adjacent[i][2];// new min
                    per = i; // for later use
                }
            }
           if(currentX == endX && currentY == endY)// makes sure that adjacent isn't at end place
            {

                open[endX, endY] = true;
            }

            currentX = Mathf.RoundToInt((int)adjacent[(int)per][0]);//new current
            currentY = Mathf.RoundToInt(adjacent[(int)per][1]);


            opens[currentX, currentY] = true;// tracks data

            closed[currentX, currentY] = false;//tracks data

        }
        open = opens;
    }
   float[][] Adjacent (int currentX, int currentY, float endX, float endY, float startX, float startY)
    {
     //creating adjacent squares areound current square
        float[][] adjacent = new float[4][];
        adjacent[0] = new float[3] { currentX + 1, currentY +0, HandG( currentX + 1, currentY,endX,  endY,  startX,  startY) };

       adjacent[1] = new float[3] { currentX + 1, currentY + -1, HandG(currentX + 1, currentY + -1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

        adjacent[2] = new float[3] { currentX + 0, currentY + -1, HandG(currentX + 0, currentY + -1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

      adjacent[3] = new float[3] { currentX + -1, currentY +- 01, HandG(currentX + -1, currentY +-1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

        adjacent[4] = new float[3] { currentX + -1, currentY + 0, HandG(currentX + -1, currentY, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

        adjacent[5] = new float[3] { currentX + -1, currentY + 01, HandG(currentX + -1, currentY + 1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

        adjacent[6] = new float[3] { currentX,  currentY + 1, HandG(currentX , currentY + 1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };

        adjacent[7] = new float[3] { currentX + 1, currentY + 1, HandG(currentX + 1, currentY + 1, endX, endY, startX, startY) };


        return adjacent;
    }

    float HandG (float currentX, float currentY,float endX, float endY, float startX, float startY )
    {
      //creates g of a*
        float g  = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(currentX + -startX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(currentY + -startY, 2));
       //creates h of a*
        float h = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(currentX + -endX, 2) + Mathf.Pow(currentY + -endY, 2));
        //creates f of a*
        float f =g + h;


        return f;
    }
}
```

The river class using this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rivers : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   public Color[] MakeRiver (Color[] color, int mapHeight, int mapWidth)
    {
        Color[] colorss = color;// makes color[]
        APath path = new APath();
      path.FindPath(20,20,9,19);// makes path. Set certain values for testing
        bool[,] open = path.open;// gets path from that class
        for(int y = 0;y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x< mapWidth; x++)
            {
                if(open[x,y] == true)
                {

                    colorss[y * mapWidth + x] = Color.red;// shows the river.
                }
            }
        }




        return colorss;
    }
}
```

If anybody, is able to see the issue, I would be very grateful. Thank you for reading my question, and have a wonderful, spectacular day.

Comment: To be honest there is so much going wrong here it's hard to help. I really feel like it would be best if you read more documentation about a* and follow a guide. A complete answer to your question would have to be a complete guide to a* anyway. I see some stuff associated with a*, but everything is wrongly implemented, sorry:-(

Comment: There are some key indicators even in your own comments that something went wrong, the fact you put in a 1000 for loop because of endless loop.. there are plenty of tutorials on a* and, well as this doesnt work its not on the good list, have a search on youtube for a* codemonkey does a good one, but it is a simple algorithum and can be mind numbingly fast

Comment: Do you have any particular reason implementing A* by yourself? There are literally dozens of free and excellent implementations of it for Unity. [This](https://arongranberg.com/astar/) being my favorite.

Comment: I implemented this myself because I'm not using a grid.

Comment: Also, what did @Knoop mean by there is a lot going wrong?

Comment: @TheWhiteRice2006 Where to start...I'll try to list a few things among all the things going wrong: `HandG` instead of actual cost to reach a node it also uses a heuristic to calculate the cost of `g`. Instead of keeping a list of all open nodes and selecting the best from those you just check the adjacent nodes to the current nodes and check which is best of those. Your ` closed` will never contain any `true` value. When calculating adjacent nodes you don't take bounds into account so you can get index exceptions.

Comment: @Knoop thanks. I'll be sure to change those things. Am I calculating anything else wrong?

Comment: while you maybe arent using a grid, the fact you have 8 choices, boils it down to a grid like structure, just maybe in your case all 8 have equal cost of choice.  So, Id really suggest the normal a* method, where you put everything in an open list, and as you have calculated the cost, you move them to closed, and find the next cheapest to start from..

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am glad that people are able to help me.