# Issues with A* implementation, without a grid, in Unity 3D, in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding

I am making a river generator, and I am using a* pathfinding to make it. Earlier I made one and had a few issues, [Custom made a* Path finding isn't working very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245811/custom-made-a-path-finding-isnt-working-very-well?noredirect=1#comment106574858_60245811). I remade it according to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alU04hvz6L4 except I didn't use a grid, and used something else. I am sure that this is the cause of my issues, but I don't know the solution. The issue is that there is no path when I use this.
The code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
public class APath 
{
    private int StraightCost = 10;
    private int DiagonalStraigtCost = 14;
    public APathNode[,] all;
    public bool[,] pathDraw;
    public List<APathNode> open;
    private List<APathNode> closed;
    private float width;
    private float height;
    public int currentX, currentY;

    public List<APathNode> FindPath(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
    {
       //all nodes
        all = new APathNode[75, 75];  
      //start node
        APathNode start = new APathNode(startX,startY);
        //end node
        APathNode end = new APathNode(endX, endY);
       //open list
        open = new List<APathNode> { start };
        //closed list
        closed = new List<APathNode>();

        //intializes all
        for(int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
        {
            for(int y =0; y < 75; y++)
            {
                APathNode pathNode = new APathNode(x, y);

                pathNode.g = int.MaxValue;

                pathNode.f = pathNode.g + pathNode.h;
                pathNode.cameFrom = null;
                all[x, y] = pathNode;

            }
        }
      //intializes start node
        start.g = 0;
        start.h = CalculateH(start,end);
        start.f = start.g + start.h;

        //while loop for algorithm
        while(open.Count > 0)
        {
         //Find lowest value
            APathNode current = LowestF(open);
        //if this is the end value
            if(current == end)
            {

                return CalculatePath(end);
            }
         //add check to closed and remove it from open
            open.Remove(current);
            closed.Add(current);

            //checks neighbors
            foreach (APathNode neighbors in GetNeighbors(current))
            {
                if (closed.Contains(neighbors)) continue;

                int tentativeGCost = (int)current.g + (int)CalculateH(current, neighbors);
                if(tentativeGCost < neighbors.g)
                {
                  //updates neighbor
                    neighbors.cameFrom = current;
                    neighbors.g = tentativeGCost;
                    neighbors.h = CalculateH(neighbors, end);
                    neighbors.f = neighbors.g + neighbors.h;

                    //if neighbor isn't in open
                    if (!open.Contains(neighbors))
                    {//add it
                        open.Add(neighbors);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;


    }
    private List<APathNode> GetNeighbors (APathNode current)
    {
        //neighbors
        List<APathNode> neighbors = new List<APathNode>();
       //left check
        if(current.selectX -1 >= 0)
        {
           //left
            neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX - 1, current.selectY]);
            //left down
            if (current.selectY - 1 >= 0) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX - 1, current.selectY - 1]);
            //left up
            if (current.selectY + 1 < 75) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX - 1, current.selectY + 1]);
        }
       //right check
        if (current.selectX + 1 < 75)
        {
           //right
            neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX + 1, current.selectY]);
            //right down
            if (current.selectY - 1 >= 0) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX + 1, current.selectY - 1]);
            //right up
            if (current.selectY + 1 < 75) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX + 1, current.selectY + 1]);
        }
        // up
        if (current.selectY - 1 >= 0) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX, current.selectY - 1]);
      //down
        if (current.selectY + 1 < 75) neighbors.Add(all[current.selectX, current.selectY + 1]);
        return neighbors;


    }


    private List<APathNode> CalculatePath (APathNode end)
    {
        //path
        List<APathNode> path = new List<APathNode>();
        // adds end
        path.Add(end);
      //updates current
        APathNode current = end;
        //updates path
        pathDraw[current.selectX, current.selectY] = true;
        //while their are still previous nodes
        while (current.cameFrom != null)
        {
            //add to path
            path.Add(current.cameFrom);
            //updates current
            current = current.cameFrom;
         //updates path draw
            pathDraw[current.selectX, current.selectY] = true;
        }
       // reverses path
        path.Reverse();
        return path;
    }
    public int CalculateH (APathNode a, APathNode b)
    {
        //h calculating
        int xDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.selectX - b.selectX);
        int yDistance = Mathf.Abs(a.selectY - a.selectY);
        int remaining = Mathf.Abs(xDistance - yDistance);
        return DiagonalStraigtCost * Mathf.Min(xDistance, yDistance) + StraightCost * remaining;

    }


    private APathNode LowestF (List<APathNode> pathNodeList)
    {
        // gets lowest f
        APathNode lowest = pathNodeList[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < pathNodeList.Count; i++)
        {

            if(pathNodeList[i].f < lowest.f)
            {
                lowest = pathNodeList[i];
            }
        }

        return lowest;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rivers : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Color[] MakeRiver (Color[] color, int mapHeight, int mapWidth)
    {
        Color[] colorss = color;// makes color[]
        APath path = new APath();
        List<APathNode> p = path.FindPath(0, 0, 16, 2);
        bool[,] rPath = path.pathDraw;
        // gets path from that class
     for(int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++)
        {
            colorss[p[i].selectY * 75 + p[i].selectX] = Color.red;
        }
       // shows the river.
        return colorss;
    }





    }
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class APathNode

{
    //x, and y
    public int selectX, selectY;
    //constructor
    public APathNode(int selectX, int selectY)
    {
        this.selectX = selectX;
        this.selectY = selectY;
    }
    //g
    public float g;
   //h
    public float h;

    //f
    public float f;
    public APathNode cameFrom;

}
```

If anyone could help me I would be glad. It would be my weekend's work be worth it. Thank you and have a good day/evening/night.

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: Whenever I use it, there isn't any path at all. @Triby

Comment: This is a dup of your own question [Custom made a\* Path finding isn't working very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60245811/custom-made-a-path-finding-isnt-working-very-well)

Comment: That A* methods return a List of nodes, and you have to program de route over that list of nodes, have you checked the List<APathNode> returned by your method CalculatePath ()?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still want to use A* because dynamic navmesh generation works better than A* and gives better results on Unity profiler too

Comment: Yeah, could you share a link to me.

Comment: You can just follow the tutorial by Brackeys for path finding.. to make it dynamic use the script.. i don’t remember the class name.. but you can dynamically bake the nav mesh using class.buildnavmesh.